# Console Log Error when implementing Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Right now i'm implementing firebase push notification on android, and I got console log error in firebase function's log.
I'm deployig the notification using JavaScript

I installed Node.js and npm both successfully in my system
and in the command prompt the function is also deployed on the firebase function's side successfully but in the log I got error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'u_id' of undefined**

please help!

this is my index.js file

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database
                        .ref('/Notifications/{u_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event  => {

                            const u_id = event.params.u_id;
                            const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

                            console.log('The User Id is ', u_id);
                            // console.log('Notification', n_id);
                        });
```

and this is my **Firebase Log**

[image: Firebase Console Log]

also the dependency is added

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

google services

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is cmd prompt that shows the notification function

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not retrieving the data correctly from the event:

if you are using firebase functions ver >1.0 (the newer non-beta ver - check your package.json):

```
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{u_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change,context) => {
    const u_id = context.params.u_id;
...
```

This interface has changed between beta (ver <1.0) and GA (ver >=1.0)

Comment: thanks for the help, but here occurs another problem it says "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"

Comment: it works now successfully, thank you very much for the help